# Setting values of descriptor attribute in Python using class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

I am trying to understand how descriptor works in Python. I have below code snippet.

```
>>> class D(object):
    def __get__(*_):
        print('get called')
    def __set__(*_):
        print('set called')
>>> 
>>> class Person(object):
    name = D()

>>> 
>>> jane = Person()
>>> jane.name
get called
>>> jane.name = 'Janny'
set called
>>> Person.name
get called
>>> Person.name = 'Jack'
>>>
```

When descriptor attribute `name` is accessed using class name i.e. `Person.name` get method is called. However, when I try to set the value using same way i.e. `Person.name = 'Jack'` set is not called. Here, I was expecting set to be called.

I am unable to understand this behavior.

I am using Python 3.8.

Answer (score 3):

Decorators are defined at the object's type e.g. in your example for object `jane`, the descriptor referred by `name` must be defined at the type of `jane` i.e. on the body of class `Person`. So in the case of a class, the descriptor needs to be defined at the metaclass of the class (as a class is an instance of its metaclass) to have the descriptor invoked for the given attribute lookup on the class object.

In your example, `jane.name` and `jane.name = 'Janny'` worked as the descriptor referred by `name` is defined at the body of class `Person` i.e. it exists on the `Person.__dict__` (which is a `mappingproxy` object and is read-only). Next, `Person.name` found the attribute on the `Person.__dict__` and saw that it has the `__get__` attribute so is a descriptor hence called `__get__` for retrieving value. Now, when you set `Person.name = 'Jack'`, it sets the `name` attribute to refer to string object `Jack` via `Person.__setattr__`, dropping the previous reference to descriptor `D`. So now all references to `name` e.g. if you do `jane.name`/`Person.name`, you would get the string `Jack`.

---

Here's an example of how you can achieve the desired behavior by applying the descriptor at the metaclass as well:

```
In [15]: class FooDec: 
    ...:     def __get__(self, instance, owner=None): 
    ...:         print(f'__get__ called with: instance: {instance}, owner: {owner}') 
    ...:     def __set__(self, instance, value): 
    ...:         print(f'__set__ called with: instance: {instance}, value: {value}')  
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [16]: class Meta(type): 
    ...:     foo = FooDec() 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [17]: class People(metaclass=Meta): 
    ...:     foo = FooDec() 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [18]: People.foo                                                                                                                                                                                         
__get__ called with: instance: <class '__main__.People'>, owner: <class '__main__.Meta'>

In [19]: People.foo = 100                                                                                                                                                                                   
__set__ called with: instance: <class '__main__.People'>, value: 100

In [20]: p = People()                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [21]: p.foo                                                                                                                                                                                              
__get__ called with: instance: <__main__.People object at 0x7faa0b2cb1c0>, owner: <class '__main__.People'>

In [22]: p.foo = 1                                                                                                                                                                                          
__set__ called with: instance: <__main__.People object at 0x7faa0b2cb1c0>, value: 1
```